# Unable to click on Element in Selenium Google Developer Community Website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fetch data around all past events for Google Developer Community and unable to click on particular elements using Selenium.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://gdg.community.dev/gdg-albuquerque/")

master_df = pd.DataFrame()
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.button-styles__buttonHover_n4oye")
if len(buttons) == 9: # If total buttons available are 9 (then load more will be there)
    for index, button in enumerate(buttons):
        if index == 7: # Find load more button
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
            clickable_button = button.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Layout-styles__flexContainer_77byt")
            clickable_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when an element is not present in the visible area of a web page, Selenium cannot click this element and will raise an exception. Explicit conditions like `element_to_be_clickable` are also not working here.

So we could scroll to the visible area with JavaScript and wait for a while (maybe JavaScript needs some time to notice that). And then the click action will work.

```py
clickable_button = button.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Layout-styles__flexContainer_77byt")
# Another 2 new lines
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", clickable_button)
time.sleep(1)
clickable_button.click()
```

What's more, instead of iterating over `buttons` and checking the `index` every time, you could try to access it by using `buttons[7]` or even directly get the element by

```py
clickable_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Load more']")
```

which I think is more efficient and readable.